# Full screen 3 columns that stack on mobile

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

On a full sized screen, I have three images in a column format that should, all together, take up the entire screen. Right now, my code works, in that the the images take up the width of the screen and on screen less than 600px, the images stack one top of one another. But the issue is that the images are not taking up the entire width. The code is below and I am using a sample pic that is huge, but it still doesn't show the entire height of the image.

EDITED TO TAKE OUT MY ORIGINAL CODE

Okay, per comments, I have changed the code to look: http://jsfiddle.net/zx11x99x/

```css
.wrapper img{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper img{
        width:33%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
    <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
    <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
</div>
```

The problem is still that the images are not full screen, which I cannot seem to figure out.

In short, I am trying to go for this, but with the columns stacking on mobile
http://jsfiddle.net/9udg7qxg/

Comment: can you create a fiddle? you can try min-width too...

Comment: your code looks better like this : #one,#two,#three { width: 33%; float: left; } or why not just .wrapper div img{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example example example example example example example example example   http://jsfiddle.net/zx11x99x/

```
code
```

Comment: This is far more elegant than what I am using, thanks. But what about the height of the images?

Comment: np... the height is relative to width, or do you wanna do something about the height?

Comment: stack you mean be on top of eacother ... it does if you make your window smaller... the wrapper smaller than 600px...

Comment: yeah becausae that one is messed up, even the bracket counts are wrong... apply the one I use with the media query ;)

Comment: Okay, if I add height:100% to the media query, it works

Answer (score 0):

*Updated:*

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

@media (max-width:1400px) and (min-width:600px) {
.wrapper > img{
    float:left;
    max-width:33%;
    }
}

@media (max-width:600px) and (min-width:100px) {
    .wrapper > img{
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zx11x99x/2/)

Just also make sure you use the correct Meta tag.

Comment: Hmm.. tried all of that and while it works, it is not doing what I am trying to get it to do...